# Low Faucet Flow Both Hot and Cold -- Aerator Clogged

Tags: plumbing, faucet

The water just trickles out of my bathroom faucet regardless if I turn on the hot or cold water.

It looks like this:

https://youtu.be/McQUTBu9RM8

I took out the aerator, and this black stuff came out:

[image]

It was like black sand. When I took out and cleaned the aerator, I still get low flow.

It looks like this:

https://youtu.be/A_CvX9NefZo

I'm thinking that replacing the faucet is the quickest way to fix this. Any tips appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You have sediment in your pipes.

Replacing the valve will not fix this.

Try thoroughly flushing your lines through faucets that don't have aerators. Such as, the outside hose valves and utility sinks. Remove the aerators from other valves and flush those lines too.

Then see if you get better flow.

Good luck!

Comment: Yep, and then have a plumber install a particle filter at the inlet to the house.  ---   and remember to replace the filter every now and then!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm not sure how this would fix the faucet. Do you recommend that I replace the faucet?